# to design a 2nd Order Sallen-Key HPF

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, non-inverting

I am having trouble solving the following exercise.
[image: I am having trouble with the damping constant as you can see. It is giving me a gain less than 1. I am following my course notes but can't solve this question. Any help would be great!]

I am having trouble with the damping constant as you can see. It is giving me a gain less than 1. I am following my course notes but can't solve this question. Any help would be great!

"Design a 2nd Order SK HP filter with f_c = 3KHz and zeta = 1.3. Use C=10nF and R2 = 10kOhms. I used zeta = 0.5*(3-G) to find gain, which gave me 0.4. Since it's a non-inv amp this isn't possible and hence why i'm stuck

Comment: I can't see, you posted a washed out picture.

Comment: "Design a 2nd Order SK HP filter with f_c = 3KHz and zeta = 1.3. Use C=10nF and R2 = 10kOhms. I used zeta = 0.5*(3-G) to find gain, which gave me 0.4. Since it's a non-inv amp this isn't possible and hence why i'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

Set

$$ \frac{R_4}{R_3}\Big(\frac{s^2}{s^2+s*(\frac{1}{R_1C_1}+\frac{1}{R_2C_2})+\frac{1}{R_1C_1R_2C_2}}\Big)= \frac{s^2}{s^2+s\zeta(2\pi f_c)+(2\pi f_c)^2}$$

The s term and constant in the s-polynomial should equal each other.

$$ \frac{1}{R_1C_1}+\frac{1}{R_2C_2}=\zeta(2\pi f_c)$$
$$ \frac{1}{R_1C_1R_2C_2}=(2\pi f_c)^2$$

I couldn't get it working without choosing one of the capacitors as I solve the expression above for R1C1 from the bottom equation. Sine the poles should be the same  R1C1 and R2C2 need to be set to 3kHz it would make sense to choose a different capacitor. I didn't mess with the gain term because that will not change the filter poles.